# Converting characters to decimal while I need to append the values together

Tags: append, hex, character, decimal

I'm receiving two characters from a serial port let's say '\x10' and 'Q'.

I need to convert them to decimal.

Each character indicates a two byte Hex code "10" and "51"

However, I need to append them and have "1051" and then convert this to decimal to give me 4177 which indicates my voltage value multiplied by 100.

So what is the question?

I know printf("%x", ...)  gives me a HEX value however it does not give me this ability to modify and append two hex code to get one. ( It just shows the HEX format)

Then what is the actual way to convert and append them together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was pretty easy but tricky. And I got confused by division in the received packet! It was just a simple hex to dec and dec to hex in order to append to chunk together!

```
    int x, y, z, v, n;

string s =  SerialBuffer ;   



char ch;

ch = SerialBuffer[17];



char ch2;

ch2 = SerialBuffer[16];// s.at(16);

x = (ch / 16);// +(int)sum;
y = (ch % 16);
z = (ch2 / 16);
v = ch2 % 16;

n = v + z * 16 + y * 256 + x * 4096;         // decimal
```